# Java 8 vs. Java 1.8 installation (directory name)

Tags: software-installation, java, openjdk

Somehow I've ended up with two directories for OpenJdk 8 on my Ubuntu 16.04 system:

1. `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64`
2. `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64`

The problem is that the first directory seems to be corrupt. If I do `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java HelloWorld` on an existing `HelloWorld.class` file, I get nothing, but doing `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java HelloWorld` produces the expected output.

Now look at this:

```
core$ ll /etc/alternatives/jav*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 42 Nov  7 11:02 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 52 Nov  2 19:32 /etc/alternatives/java.1.gz -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/java.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 Nov  2 19:35 /etc/alternatives/javac -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 53 Nov  2 19:35 /etc/alternatives/javac.1.gz -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/javac.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 45 Nov  2 19:35 /etc/alternatives/javadoc -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javadoc*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 55 Nov  2 19:35 /etc/alternatives/javadoc.1.gz -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/javadoc.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 Nov  2 19:35 /etc/alternatives/javah -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javah*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 53 Nov  2 19:35 /etc/alternatives/javah.1.gz -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/javah.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 Nov  2 19:35 /etc/alternatives/javap -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javap*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 53 Nov  2 19:35 /etc/alternatives/javap.1.gz -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/javap.1.gz
```

All of these point to the `8` directory, and not `1.8`, which is causing problems when running programs. My question is: How did this mess come about, and what's the best way to sort this out? I'd like to remove everything else and have OpenJDK 8 as my default JDK.

Comment: Which openjdk-8 packages do you have installed in your system?

Comment: @Anwar I'm not sure how to get the list, but if I hit tab autocomplete on `apt remove openjdk-8-j` I get `openjdk-8-jdk openjdk-8-jdk-headless openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jre-headless`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so the problem in my case was that I had unknowingly installed openjdk headless also, and thus ended up with two installations. I finally removed all jdks from my system and installed JDK 9 (which isn't a trouble-free installation, I might add!) and now everything seems sorted!

Answer (score 2):

Choose Java version:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Example output:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing usr/bin/java).         
Selection     Path                                            Priority  Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0           /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java          1081     auto mode
  1           /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081     manual mode
* 2           /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java          1081     manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

You may also see the alternatives for `java`, `javac` by using the `--list` option:

```
sudo update-alternatives --list java
sudo update-alternatives --list javac
```

Comment: Thanks, but here's what I get in output (providing pastebin link because of formatting issues): http://pastebin.com/yt0S0Adw

I know that something is amiss in my system. I maybe messed up something.